# Bad value during floating point read

Tags: linux, file-io, fortran, gfortran

I'm running some simulation code using ubuntu and I keep running into the same error. I am trying to read data from the .dat file. But there is some error which I could not find.

This is error message:

```
At line 1939 of file CompoundMPIBSC20200823.f90 (unit = 11, file = 'C-340120b.dat') 
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read"
```

And C-340120b.dat file looks like this:
**C-340120b.dat file**

```
 6      10  1.531581196563372e-15
 0.0014553174 0.0055615333 0.0119703978 0.0203850084 0.0305528957 0.0422600997 0.0553257997 0.0695976542 0.0849475255 0.1012676622
 0.1184670631 0.1364683308 0.1552047081 0.1746171362 0.1946516651 0.2152575030 0.2363847713 0.2579826431 0.2799978445 0.3023733948
 0.3250475021 0.3479528735 0.3710162901 0.3941586119 0.4172949742 0.4403351781 0.4631846022 0.4857450840 0.5079162267 0.5295967855
 0.5506862041 0.5710862773 0.5907027347 0.6094469646 0.6272378474 0.6440030470 0.6596808652 0.6742212377 0.6875870601 0.6997550335
 0.7107163254 0.7204769965 0.7290581527 0.7364958286 0.7428406051 0.7481569620 0.7525223874 0.7560262383 0.7587683705 0.7608575997
 0.7624099924 0.7635469966 0.7643935146 0.7650758792 0.7657198055 0.7664483527 0.7673799150 0.7686263022 0.7702908977 0.7724669898
 0.7752362202 0.7786672785 0.7828147402 0.7877181912 0.7934015601 0.7998727305 0.8071233638 0.8151290525 0.8238496666 0.8332299862
 0.8432005800 0.8536788860 0.8645704950 0.8757706624 0.8871659719 0.8986361128 0.9100557539 0.9212965992 0.9322292652 0.9427254733
 0.9526599682 0.9619125838 0.9703700425 0.9779277777 0.9844915839 0.9899791031 0.9943211058 0.9974625834 0.9993636185 1.0000000000
 6      11  1.475893077189510e-15
 0.0016525844 0.0062956494 0.0135059282 0.0229208176 0.0342303569 0.0471704147 0.0615165460 0.0770787515 0.0936966304 0.1112350678
 0.1295802432 0.1486359799 0.1683205560 0.1885633307 0.2093018003 0.2304793480 0.2520427451 0.2739399970 0.2961185348 0.3185236648
 0.3410972443 0.3637767806 0.3864948806 0.4091790904 0.4317517598 0.4541305840 0.4762291287 0.4979578467 0.5192252758 0.5399391683
 0.5600082344 0.5793434896 0.5978599757 0.6154784463 0.6321271026 0.6477428598 0.6622731054 0.6756767045 0.6879251243 0.6990032865
 0.7089101737 0.7176591771 0.7252781911 0.7318094543 0.7373091004 0.7418464594 0.7455031054 0.7483717148 0.7505546359 0.7521623630
 0.7533118077 0.7541244615 0.7547244701 0.7552366540 0.7557845046 0.7564881945 0.7574626361 0.7588156121 0.7606460387 0.7630423235
 0.7660809513 0.7698252039 0.7743241221 0.7796116798 0.7857062078 0.7926100427 0.8003094738 0.8087748795 0.8179612002 0.8278085409
 0.8382431405 0.8491784407 0.8605164079 0.8721490905 0.8839601234 0.8958267320 0.9076214149 0.9192140226 0.9304737122 0.9412709632
 0.9514795610 0.9609785827 0.9696542131 0.9774014787 0.9841259295 0.9897450178 0.9941894123 0.9974040480 0.9993489837 1.0000000000
...
...
...
 6   30500  2.203435261320421e-18
 0.5647132406 0.8435296561 0.9197993603 0.9501219587 0.9657979424 0.9751478483 0.9812026747 0.9853454006 0.9882967561 0.9904674356
 0.9921063590 0.9933715119 0.9943670960 0.9951635956 0.9958099778 0.9963412928 0.9967830203 0.9971540150 0.9974684566 0.9977371653
 0.9979685074 0.9981690312 0.9983439172 0.9984973073 0.9986325426 0.9987523421 0.9988589360 0.9989541675 0.9990395697 0.9991164266
 0.9991858197 0.9992486651 0.9993057428 0.9993577205 0.9994051720 0.9994485928 0.9994884125 0.9995250049 0.9995586968 0.9995897744
 0.9996184895 0.9996450644 0.9996696956 0.9996925575 0.9997138054 0.9997335777 0.9997519982 0.9997691778 0.9997852163 0.9998002034
 0.9998142198 0.9998273389 0.9998396267 0.9998511432 0.9998619429 0.9998720754 0.9998815859 0.9998905154 0.9998989017 0.9999067791
 0.9999141790 0.9999211303 0.9999276594 0.9999337906 0.9999395461 0.9999449463 0.9999500100 0.9999547546 0.9999591958 0.9999633483
 0.9999672254 0.9999708395 0.9999742019 0.9999773228 0.9999802118 0.9999828775 0.9999853278 0.9999875699 0.9999896101 0.9999914544
 0.9999931080 0.9999945754 0.9999958609 0.9999969680 0.9999978997 0.9999986585 0.9999992466 0.9999996655 0.9999999164 1.0000000000
```

The 3 dots in the above data file are just to tell you that there are many more entries in the file. These dots are not there in the original file.

And program :
**file CompoundMPIBSC20200823.f90**

```
open(11,file=fname(mel),status='old',form='formatted')
open(12,file=fname1(mel),status='old',form='formatted')
do men=1,nen !nen=75:energy intervals Energy split number cycle
    !!write(iw,*) 'mel,men:',mel,men
    read (11,'(i2,I7,d22.15/(10f13.10))') na,nenerg,tcrpc,(rpw(i),i=1,ith)  
    read (12,'(i2,I7,d22.15/(10f15.10))') na,nenerg,tcrpc,(rpw1(i),i=1,ith)  
    !!write(iw,*) 'mel,men,na,nenerg:',mel,men,na,nenerg,tcrpc
    ftcs(men)=tcrpc ! corresponds to the total elastic scattering cross section at the energy
    penergy(men)=nenerg/1000.
    rpw(ith)=1.
    !---------------------------
```

line 1939 is

```
read (11,'(i2,I7,d22.15/(10f13.10))') na,nenerg,tcrpc,(rpw(i),i=1,ith)
```

I've tried different modifications of the code but didn't get any results.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should really find out which values did it try to read. Add a print statement writing the contents that was just read.

Comment: @VladimirF but I don't understand how to find which values are read or which ones cause an error. where print statement should be added?

Comment: If you add a write statement immediately after line 1939, to print out everything line 1939 reads in, then the last thing written before the error will be the last succesful read from line 1939. If you find this line in the input file, you will be able to see what line 1939 is trying to read in when it fails.

Comment: @veryreverie, You mean that I should add a write statement after read (line 1939) to keep checking if that works or not? And you mean the same write statement which is mentioned in program (!!write(iw,*) 'mel,men,na,nenerg:',mel,men,na,nenerg,tcrpc).

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can just uncomment that line. (although I have no idea what `mel` is from the snippet you have given).

Comment: @veryreverie, mel shows the element name. I will check by the way you mentioned. hope It works.

Comment: @veryreverie it doesn't work. By adding a write statement, the error remains the same. No effect at all.

Comment: If it never writes anything, then you know it's the first time that line 1939 is called that it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241326/discussion-between-iman-and-veryreverie).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have spaces padding the fields in your data file, but not in your read format. The first line of your file (with column labels) is

```
000000000111111111122222222223333
123456789012345678901234567890123
 6      10  1.531581196563372e-15
```

so splitting this into `i2,I7,d22.15` gives

```
i2 |    I7   |          d22.15        |
00 | 0000000 | 1111111111222222222233 | 33
12 | 3456789 | 0123456789012345678901 | 23
 6 |       1 | 0  1.531581196563372e- | 15
```

which is clearly not as intended.

There are two ways around this problem:

1. As Ian Bush points out, you can forego the read format entirely, and used list-directed input, as

```
read (11,*) na,nenerg,tcrpc,(rpw(i),i=1,ith)
```

This will parse your file token by token rather than relying on column widths, and is usually a much better option for parsing data files.

2. If you must use a read format, you need to add space padding to it, e.g.
   `'(i2,X,I7,X,d22.15/10(X,f13.10))'`, which will then split the input string as

```
i2 | X |    I7   | X |        d22.15
00 | 0 | 0000001 | 1 | 1111111122222222223333
12 | 3 | 4567890 | 1 | 2345678901234567890123
 6 |   |      10 |   |  1.531581196563372e-15
```

Comment: Or quite possible simply `read( 11, * ) ...`  - but I haven't checked the specific details here. Much more often that not is seems to me that formats in reads are just an unnecessary complication

Comment: @veryreverie just by using your space padding suggestion, the error remains the same.

Comment: @IanBush by using read(11,*)... ,now another error pop up which is:                                               At line 1939 of file CompoundMPIBSC20200823.f90 (unit = 11, file = 'C-340120b.dat')
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input

Comment: @Iman can you give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a new Stack Overflow question? (i.e. first find the place in the input file which is failing to parse, and give all the details we need to compile your code, including the declarations of all of your variables).

Comment: @veryreverie in the input file which I shared above, I didn't find the error place. so what I can share in a new question, and also shared that part of code that caused the error(the complete code is too long to be shared here), so what more do you need to know and asked for? These continuous errors drained my energy.

Comment: If you use `write` to find out what is being `read` successfully, you can work out which part of the file is not being `read` successfully. Then only include that part of the input file in your question. And a minimal reproducible example just needs the parts of the code you've shown here, plus details like the decalaration and initialisation of the variables you've shown. It should only need ~10-20 lines of code tops. Basically it's the smallest amount of code and input file needed for us to actually run it and get the same error message as you. Otherwise we're just guessing :)

Comment: @veryreverie But after using "write", I didn't get any changes in the file or in error. same error "At line 1939 of file CompoundMPIBSC20200823.f90 (unit = 11, file = 'C-340120b.dat')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read" occurred.

Comment: A line like `write(*,*) men,na,nenerg,tcrpc` just after line 1939 of your code will write a line to the terminal every time line 1939 executes sucessfully. If it writes nothing then this means that line 1939 **never** executes sucessfully, and so it must be the first time that line 1939 executes where it fails, i.e. when reading the first line(s) of the file.

Comment: @veryreverie I will again try to do this by adding write statement. Also, another suggestion for this error I got is " It is quite easy to find the error source by comparing the data file with the code. The data type and the number of digits must be the same." But I compared the data file with code many times. I don't know is there something wrong with the data file or the number of digits is not the same.